# Shell script to pass multiple arguments with options in command line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I have the script, I need to execute this script like this:

```
./create_endpoint.sh --controller-ip 10.20.20.1 --controller-name User1.
```

But its executing like this:

```
./create_endpoint.sh 10.20.20.1 User1
```

The script:

```
CONTROLLER_IP=""
CONTROLLER_NAME=""
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]
  then
    CONTROLLER_IP=$1
    CONTROLLER_NAME=$2
  else
    echo "Usage : create_endpoint.sh --controller-ip <Controller IP> --controller-name"
    exit 1  
fi
echo $CONTROLLER_IP
echo $CONTROLLER_NAME
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe using `getopts` is a better solution for advance use, when you need flexibility on the amount of arguments passed.

This is a working example:

```
if (($# == 0)); then
  echo "Please pass argumensts -p <pkg1><pkg2>... -m <email1><email2>.."
  exit 2
fi
while getopts ":p:m:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    p)
      echo "-p was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      PKGS=$OPTARG
      ;;
    m)
      echo "-m was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      MAIL=$OPTARG
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
echo "go thru selection"
for PKG in $PKGS;
do
 echo "ARG_PKG: $PKG"
done
echo "go thru selection email"
for M in $MAIL;
do
 echo "ARG_MAIL: $M"
done
exit 0
```

ref.. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

OUTPUT:

```
bash t -p "pkg1 pkg2 pkg3" -m "bobo@m.com boba@m.com"
-p was triggered, Parameter: pkg1 pkg2 pkg3
-m was triggered, Parameter: bobo@m.com boba@m.com
go thru selection
ARG_PKG: pkg1
ARG_PKG: pkg2
ARG_PKG: pkg3
go thru selection email
ARG_MAIL: bobo@m.com
ARG_MAIL: boba@m.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the flags `--controller-ip` and `--controller-name` counts in argument list too.

You should rather access the arguments with `$2` and `$4` and also, of course, check the argument before to be sure you are affecting the correct variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if you are looking for this

Script:

```
[[ "$#" -ne 4 ]] && { echo "Usage : create_endpoint.sh --controller-ip <Controller IP> --controller-name"; exit 1; }
[[ "$1" = "--controller-ip" ]] &&  CONTROLLER_IP=$2
[[ "$3" = "--controller-name" ]] &&  CONTROLLER_NAME=$4

echo $CONTROLLER_IP
echo $CONTROLLER_NAME
```

Comment: yeah, like above. Can you give some examples. Sometime I pass one argument or three arguments depends upon the requirement. how can i validate and execute

Comment: if no of arguments will vary then check the $# -ge 2. Then check for not-null values.